# ASP.NET MVC HTTPGET action: array parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How to solve this case?

Request: http://example.com/test?geoPoints[0]**[Latitude]**=123&geoPoints[0]**[Longitude]**=1

My controller action:

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Test([FromUri] List<GeoPoint> geoPoints)
```

With request http://example.com/test?geoPoints[0]**.Latitude**=123&geoPoints[0]**.Longitude**=1 is ok, but I need to solve the first case.

Please help.

I'm sorry, my English is not good.

Comment: What technology is that? Please - tag your question accordingly.

Comment: I´m sory. ASP.NET .net framework 4.5.1

Comment: You can't unless you create a custom `ModelBinder`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom `ModelBinder` like this(just for the reference):

```
public class GeoPointModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public static Regex regex = new Regex(@"^geoPoints\[\(d+)\]\[(longitude|latitude)\]$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var query = actionContext.Request.RequestUri.Query;

        var parameters = query
            .Split(new char[] { '&' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Select(it => it.Split('='))
            .Where(it => regex.IsMatch(it[0]))
            .ToDictionary(it => it[0], it => it[1]);

        var points = parameters
            .Select(it => new GeoPoint())
            .ToList();

        foreach (var parameter in parameters)
        {
            var match = regex.Match(parameter.Key);
            var firstGroup = match.Groups[1];
            var secondGroup = match.Groups[2];

            int index = int.Parse(firstGroup.Value);
            string field = secondGroup.Value;

            if (string.Equals(field, "latitude", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                points[index].Latitude = parameter.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                points[index].Longitude = parameter.Value;
            }
        }

        bindingContext.Model = points;
        return true;
    }
}
...

[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Test([ModelBinder(typeof(GeoPointModelBinder))]List<GeoPoint> geoPoints) 
{ 
   //... 
}
```